# Is there a way to prevent Blender from creating .fbm folders when exporting to .fbx?

Tags: export, file-format

I frequently have to export models in Blender to .fbx files for a Unity game I'm working on, and although the models are coming out OK, Unity always creates .fbm folders when the models get imported. Models exported from Maya also have this problem unless you go into the FBX options and disable "embed media". Blender 2.74 has an option to embed textures in fbx files (which is presumably the same thing as "embed media"), but even though this is disabled by default, I still get .fbm folders being created when models are imported by Unity.

Normally, this wouldn't be a big deal, but the folders get created on the system of everbody working on the game, and because Mercurial/GIT ignore empty folders, and Unity creates .meta files for empty folders, cleaning up the mess gets way more annoying than it needs to be and that's why I would really love a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should delete the material on the object you're exporting in Blender and have the material importing disabled in Unity.

Comment: Yes, this is the solution I think. In our project there is a guy using Maya who frequently checks in models with embedded textures, which was causing the problem. However, I haven't had any issues using Blender for quite some time, so I assume that the fbx exporter was fixed. Perhaps I was using files that had embedded materials and not deleting the materials before re-exporting.